# Eventsource NetworkError: 406 Not Acceptable

Tags: c#, jquery, eventsource

I got **NetworkError: 406 Not Acceptable** when request for json files with Eventsource.The code is as below.

```
 var source = new EventSource('/liveMap/pesron1.json');

                    source.addEventListener("open", function (event) {
                        console.log('Processing started...')
                    }, false);


                    source.addEventListener("error", function (event) {
                        if (event.eventPhase == EventSource.CLOSED) {
                            console.log('error...')
                            source.close();
                        }
                    }, false);

                    source.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
                        console.log('data ', event.data)
                        var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
                    }, false);
```

And the json file is geojson as below :

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"1850220292","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[51.4220625,35.7131196]},"properties":{"id":"1850220292","Description":"","Url":"liveMap/3131.json","Date":"1396/10/07  12:40:08","Accuracy":"19.573","Bearing":"0","Speed":"0","Direction":"0","GPSState":"0","PowerState":"0","Latitude":"35.7131196","Longitude":"51.4220625","BusinessName":"m-Ali","LocationName":""}}]}
```

Comment: should it be '/liveMap/person1.json'  ?

Comment: you mean url is wrong? it still have error if set full url for example 'http://192.168.0.201:8081/livemap/person1.json'.I can get it by $.Ajax but eventsource is not works for me

Comment: "The EventSource interface is used to receive server-sent events"   from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource    so maybe EventSource only works for server-side code files not a JSON file?

Comment: I wanna use json file for realtime map in 'leaflet realtime' plugin.like this post :https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-realtime/blob/gh-pages/busses.js .but eventsource not works for me.